# How can I prove the following question

Tags: abstract-algebra, normed-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $(A,+,.,*,\|.\|)$  denotes complex Banach algebra such that $\|.\|$ norm on $A$ satisfies $$\|f*g\||  \leq  \| f\|.\|g\|$$ and $e$ is the identity element. How can I prove that if $\| x\|<1$ then 
$$(e-x)^{-1}=e+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots?$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series

Comment: It's precisely the same as the proof of the sum of a geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

Define $S_n= e+x+...+x^n$. Since $A$ is a Banach algebra, $||x^n||\leq ||x||^n$, hence $\{S_n\}$ forms a Cauchy sequence. Thus, it is convergent to, say, $S$.

Since $S \cdot(e-x)= \lim_{n\to \infty} S_n \cdot (e-x)= \lim_{n\to\infty} e -x^{n+1}= e$ and analogously $(e-x) \cdot S= e$, $(e-x)^{-1}=S$.